# Sum values in two list of tuples grouped by key

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two list of tuples and I would like to group the total by each key (key, value).

Please note the key 142.

```
a = [(1713, 1L), (745, 1L), (142, 1L)]
b = [(1298, 1L), (620, 1L), (142, 1L)]

a_b = [(1713, 1L), (745, 1L), (1298, 1L), (620, 1L), (142, 2L)]
```

I am trying this, but obviously will fail when a key is new in b:

```
d={}
for k,v in a:
    for k1,v1 in b:
        if k == k1:
            print k
            d[k] = v+v1
        else:
            d[k] = v
print d #{1713: 1L, 142: 2L, 745: 1L}
```

Comment: is `1L` supposed to be a string? `"1L"`? If so, it's unclear how `"1L"+"1L"="2L"`

Comment: @kevinkayaks That is a long integer

Comment: It's an artefact from a deprecated version of the language from eons ago.

Comment: If this were python3, I would be tempted to recommend something like `list({**dict(a), **dict(b)}.items())` (I recommend switching)

Comment: oh, thanks for the lesson. I never coded in python2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `collections.OrderedDict` by iterating through the combined list of `a` and `b` in reverse, since the latter of the duplicating keys take precedence in your merging logic, after which you can obtain the desired list of tuples by reversing again the list of dict items:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
for k, v in reversed(a + b):
    d[k] = d.get(k, 0) + v
a_b = d.items()[::-1]
```

`a_b` becomes:

```
[(1713, 1L), (745, 1L), (1298, 1L), (620, 1L), (142, 2L)]
```

Edit: Since you now mentioned in the comments that the order of the output does not matter, you can instead use a regular dict just like you do in your question. The key here is to iterate through the combined list of `a` and `b`, and use the `dict.get` method to default the initial value of a key to `0`:

```
d = {}
for k, v in a + b:
    d[k] = d.get(k, 0) + v
a_b = d.items()
```

Comment: I am not sure f I understand correctly, but the order of merge is irrelevant in this particular case,

Comment: It's relevant because of the position of the surviving tuple. If the list was not reversed first, we would end up with `[(1713, 1L), (745, 1L), (142, 2L), (1298, 1L), (620, 1L)]` instead since the key `142` occurs at the third position first if iterating in the original direction.

Comment: What I mean is that the 142 position is irrelevant. Third or last position is not important here.

Answer (score 1):

[Counter](https://documentation.help/Python-2.7.10/collections.html#collections.Counter) is perfect for this type of situation.  Basically, it's a dictionary that knows how to add up.

```
from collections import Counter

a = [(1713, 1L), (745, 1L), (142, 1L)]
b = [(1298, 1L), (620, 1L), (142, 1L)]

a_b = Counter(dict(a)) + Counter(dict(b))
print([(k, v) for k, v in a_b.items()])
```

You would get output like this

```
[(1713, 1L), (1298, 1L), (620, 1L), (142, 2L), (745, 1L)]
```

Of course you don't really need to turn the result back to a list of tuples if you need further processing.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict as ddt
from itertools import chain

new_dic = ddt(long)
for k,v in chain(a,b):
    new_dic[k] += v
a_b = new_dic.items()
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without `import`:

```
counter = {key : 0 for key, _ in a + b}
for key, val in a + b:
    counter[key] += val
a_b = [(key, val) for key, val in counter.items()]
```